# Rellenar contorno, Python

Tags: python

Lo que estoy intentando es trabajar solo con un contorno en específico, la imagen la tengo binarizada así que solo tengo negro y blanco. Lo que quiero hacer es que ya que tengo detectados todos los contornos rellenar los otros contornos y que se pongan en color blanco. Realmente no se si eso sea posible o que podria hacer para poder eliminar los otros contornos y solo quedarme con el del centro.

Comparto el código de como he estado intentandolo pero no he tenido éxito.

Está es la imagen que cuenta con todos los contornos y quiero rellenarlos de blanco y solo quedarme con la parte de la boca en negro por lo tanto, que la imagen quede completamente en blanco a excepeción del contorno que está en la boca, ese si debe de quedar en negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('radio.jpg',0)
img = cv2.resize(image,(600,300))

#Calculo del histograma
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
b=sum(hist)
objetivo = b/2
suma=0
numero=0
final=0

for i in hist:
    suma=suma+i
    numero=numero+len(i)
    final=numero+1
    if suma > objetivo: 
       break
 
U=final-3
ResFinal=U*2
y=((30*ResFinal)/100)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,y,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Para encontrar el área, teniendo 3000 solo queda el contorno del centro.
lista = []
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 3000 and area <  10000:
        cv2.drawContours(th1, [c], 0, (0, 255, 0), 5, cv2.LINE_AA)
        print('El área es:',area)
        lista.append(area)
        resultado = sorted(lista, reverse=True)[0:-1]
        print("Áreas encontradas:", resultado)
desp = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),(-1,  0), (0,  0), (1,  0),(-1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1)]

def get_pixel(th1, x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return 0
    if x >= len(th1[0]) or y >= len(th1):
        return 0
    return th1[y][x]

def print_imagen(th1):
    for fila in th1:
        for valor    in fila:
            print(valor, end="")
        print("")
    print("")

def marcar(th1, x, y):

    th1[y][x] = 2
    for xd, yd in desp:
        xp = x + xd
        yp = y + yd
        if get_pixel(th1, xp, yp) == 1:
            marcar(th1, xp, yp)
    return th1

print_imagen(th1) # Imagen de partida.

marcar(th1, 5, 6)

        # Eliminar todos los puntos oscuros restantes

for fila in range(len(th1)):
    for columna in range(len(th1[fila])):
        if th1[fila][columna] == 1:
            th1[fila][columna] = 0

            # Imprimir la imagen limpia.
            print_imagen(th1)


cv2.imshow('Contornos',th1)      
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo simple de lo necesitas? Lo único que logre entender es que quieres que todo, excepto un área en particular se pinte de blanco.

Comment: Sí, agrego la imagen para que sea más sencillo explicarlo.

Comment: ¿Y el resultado deseado es ...? Con un imagen ...

Comment: Que toda la imagen quede en blanco excepto el contorno de la boca.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es la siguiente:

1. Identificar un pixel oscuro cualquiera dentro de la zona que se desea conservar.
2. Asignar un color intermedio (ni blanco ni negro) a ese pixel.
3. Examinar los ocho pixeles adyacentes.
4. Si un pixel adyacente es oscuro, repetir recursivamente este algoritmo a partir de ese pixel.

Al final tendremos pixeles blancos, pixeles oscuros (que no deseamos) y pixeles en un color intermedio. Sólo queda recorrer la imagen colocando en blanco todo lo que sea oscuro.

Para estos fines:

1. El valor 0 representa un pixel blanco.
2. El valor 1 representa un pixel oscuro.
3. El valor 2 representa un pixel oscuro que deseamos conservar.

Esta es la imagen de prueba:

```
  111           
   11       1   
              1 
      1         
      111  1 111
    11111  1    
     11111 1    
      1       1 
  1             
 11         1
```

almacenada en esta matriz:

```
imagen = [
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    ]
```

Para examinar los pixeles adyacentes definimos esta matriz de desplazamientos

```
desp = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
        (-1,  0), (0,  0), (1,  0),
        (-1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1)
]
```

También definimos método que nos devuelve el valor del pixel para un punto cualquiera. Si las coordenadas son ilegales, devuelve un pixel blanco. Esto nos simplifica la vida cuando examinamos pixeles cerca de los bordes, evitando indices fuera de rango.

```
def get_pixel(imagen, x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return 0
    if x >= len(imagen[0]) or y >= len(imagen):
        return 0
    return imagen[y][x]
```

Definimos la función `marcar`, que recibe una imagen y las coordenadas de un pixel oscuro cualquiera dentro del área a conservar. La función marca ese pixel y todos los pixeles oscuros conectados:

```
def marcar(imagen, x, y):
    """ Marca los pixeles oscuros dentro del área a conservar.
    @param imagen: una matriz con la imagen.
    @param x: Columna de un pixel a conservar.
    @param y: Fila del mismo pixel a conservar.        
    """
    imagen[y][x] = 2
    for xd, yd in desp:
        xp = x + xd
        yp = y + yd
        if get_pixel(imagen, xp, yp) == 1:
            marcar(imagen, xp, yp)
    return imagen
```

Lo único que resta es llamar a esta función dándole un punto de partida. Elegimos el pixel oscuro en coordenadas (5, 6) como partida:

```
marcar(imagen, 5, 6)
```

Eso seria todo.

**Demo**

El código completo, incluyendo impresión

```
imagen = [
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    ]


desp = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1),
        (-1,  0), (0,  0), (1,  0),
        (-1,  1), (0,  1), (1,  1)
]

def get_pixel(imagen, x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return 0
    if x >= len(imagen[0]) or y >= len(imagen):
        return 0
    return imagen[y][x]

def print_imagen(image):
    for fila in imagen:
        for valor in fila:
            print(valor, end="")
        print("")
    print("")

def marcar(imagen, x, y):
    """ Marca los pixeles oscuros dentro del área a conservar.
    @param imagen: una matriz con la imagen.
    @param x: Columna de un pixel a conservar.
    @param y: Fila del mismo pixel a conservar.
    """
    imagen[y][x] = 2
    for xd, yd in desp:
        xp = x + xd
        yp = y + yd
        if get_pixel(imagen, xp, yp) == 1:
            marcar(imagen, xp, yp)
    return imagen

print_imagen(imagen) # Imagen de partida.

marcar(imagen, 5, 6)

# Eliminar todos los puntos oscuros restantes

for fila in range(len(imagen)):
    for columna in range(len(imagen[fila])):
        if imagen[fila][columna] == 1:
            imagen[fila][columna] = 0

# Imprimir la imagen limpia.
print_imagen(imagen)
```

produce:

```
# Imagen original

0011100000000000
0001100000001000
0000000000000010
0000001000000000
0000001110010111
0000111110010000
0000011111010000
0000001000000010
0010000000000000
0110000000001000

# Imagen limpia

0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
0000002000000000
0000002220000000
0000222220000000
0000022222000000
0000002000000000
0000000000000000
0000000000000000
```

Aqui en versión más limpia:

```
  2         
  222       
22222       
 22222      
  2
```

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia pero no he trabajado tanto con funciones y me es un poco difícil entender al 100% todo el código. Veo que se tiene una funcion llamada 'print_imagen(th1)' (yo coloqué el th1 porque esa es mi imagen) pero me pregunto si es que la puedo graficar para ver el resultado de la imagen literalmente ya que tranto de plotear el th1 pero no lo plotea.  Actualizaré mi códio arriba para que puedas ver lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Solo quisiera ver la imagen con el código que realizaste no solo los números que me imprime, no se si es posible o yo ando haciendo cosas locas en el código.

Comment: @SheccidSeleneCortésServín Creo que si. Puedes reemplazar todo el contenido de la función `print_imagen(th1)` por el código que necesites para plotear. Es la parte adaptable del código.